# Call a generator function inside setInterval()

Tags: node.js, redux, react-redux, generator, saga

I am trying to call a generator function inside `setInterval()` method. The objective of this code is it will query a particular server for some data periodically, until it gets a non zero response. Upon getting the response it will call `storeAddress()` which is a generator function defined in the same file. 
The below code is giving me an error like this:

> SyntaxError: yield is a reserved word (248:6)

**NOTE**: I am using react-boilerplate to build my app. The above error is thrown by babel, as far as I can tell through searching internet.

- I have tried `const query = yeild call (setInterval, function(){magic code}, 10000)`. This does not give the error, but `magic code` never gets executed.
- I have tried `const query = setInterval(function* () {magic code}, 10000)` with the same effect as above.
- I have tried `const query = setInterval(yield call(function(){magic code}, 10000)` with same effect as above.
- I have tried `const query = yield call (setInterval, function(){magic code}, 10000)` with same effect as above.
- I have tried `storeAddress(action.payload, balance).next()` inside `setInterval()`. The control does flow inside `storeAddress()`, but that function also have generator calls inside, which never gets invoked. In fact nothing after the first generator call inside `storeAddress()` gets executed in this case.

  ```
  function* callSaveNewAddress(action){
    const selectedNetwork = yield select(selectNetworkId());
    let count = 1;
    let balance = 0;
    const query = setInterval(function () {
      getAddressBalance(action.payload, selectedNetwork).then(res => 
      {return balance = res.data.mempool_balance});

      if(balance > 0) {
         yield call (storeAddress, action.payload, balance);
         clearInterval(query);
      } else if(count == 90) {
         clearInterval(query);
         console.log("Nothing received in 15 minutes");
      }
    }, 10000);
  }
  ```

So how am I suppose to call `storeAddress()`, which is a generator function, inside a normal function like `setInterval()`?

Comment: Well the code only needs to `yield` once immediately before `clearInterval()` is called. Actually this is part of a redux saga, and all the functions are generators for this purpose. Turning one into normal function will lead to change all the sagas. 
What i actually need is someway to create a delayed loop which will perform the same operation, but i need to do it with the generators. It doesnt have to be `setInterval()`. Any other way of doing a delayed loop with a generator call will also work.

Answer (score 0):

```
const query= function * () {
  const runner = yield call(setInterval, () => {
    getAddressBalance(action.payload, selectedNetwork).then(res => 
    {return balance = res.data.mempool_balance});

    if(balance > 0) {
       yield call (storeAddress, action.payload, balance);
       clearInterval(query);
    } else if(count == 90) {
       clearInterval(query);
       console.log("Nothing received in 15 minutes");
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

try to use the setInterval within a call, passing through parameters the function you want to execute within it.

Comment: No, its giving the same `SyntaxError: yield is a reserved word (252:9)` error. I think thats because here also `yield` is being called inside a normal function.

What I actually need is some way to create a delayed loop with generator functions, i.e. The loop will iterate with a given delay, and once the condition is met `yield call (storeAddress, ...arguements)` will be called. It doent have to be `setInterval()`. Any other way of doing it will also work.

Comment: I understand, maybe this example can help you:
function * idMaker () {
   var index = 0;
   while (index <3)
     yield index ++;
}
let gen = idMaker ()

setInterval (() => console.log (gen.next ()), 1000)
you can declare the generating function that you want to use within the setInterval, and then invoke it within the callback in this way

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Thats what I have tried (mentioned in my last bullet note for different tries). Curiously this way of calling the generator works as in the control does flow inside the generator. But if the generator itself calls other generators, those calls are not executed. For example, `function* storeAddress()` in my case calls other generator function inside it by `yield call (someFunction)`, everything before this `yield` call gets executed, but nothing after that including the `yield` itself is executed. Its a weird mess.